# Windows Search index using a lot of cpu

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, file-search, everything

Recently I've noticed that windows search indexer is using about 15% cpu
I don't think it's been like this before, only in the last week or so
Any ideas what can cause this?

Also, I use Everything app as well.
Recently I've found that it's been taking up about 800MB of memory - consistently!
This wasn't like this previously!

Some points:

1. I am using Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
2. I recently started using window's file versioning. I have a hard drive connected to which Windows uses to back up the files
3. I am using Everything Version 1.4.0.713b (x64)

Although these might be clues, I don't understand why it should be going consistently!

Any help on these issues will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have a corrupt Windows Index. You can rebuild it by the following steps:

To rebuild the Windows Search index, head back to Control Panel > Indexing Options. Click the Advanced button and make sure you’re on the Index Settings tab of the Advanced Options window.

Under the Troubleshooting section of the Advanced Options window, find and click the Rebuild button. Windows will warn you, just as we did above, that the index rebuilding process may take a long time, and that you may not have full search functionality until it’s complete. Click OK to accept the warning and start the re-indexing process.
(Source: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-solve-windows-search-issues-index-rebuild/)

I'm also pretty sure that you don't need your Windows Indexer turned on if you are using Everythings index to search your files. In this case, you should turn it off.

Cheers,
Eric
(Full disclosure: I work for the developers of [Lookeen Search](https://lookeen.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following solved it for me - check that your active user is the owner of `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data`.

If it isn't, run commandline with admin rights:

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\
takeown /f Data /r /d y
```